# Why is my text deformed when I save as .svg and how can I fix it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

[image: **enter image description here**]

I need to put this svg image on a site. But when I created the image is deformed and looks terrible. I try in differents ways and still not working. I hope you can help me. Thanks..

Comment: Hi Victor Van den Brink, Is this a picture of the exported SVG? Did you turn the text into outlines/expand text before exporting (not sure if that matters)? Can you post the SVG code or are you uploading as .svg?

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes that is a pic of the exported SVG and yes, I turned the text into outlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Victor, before you save it as SVG you should try turning your text to outlines:

**Type > Create Outlines**

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did before..

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you export the vectors.

If you are using a vector format program, like Ilustrator, Corel or Inkscape, convert them to curves first.

But it looks you are using microsoft powerpoint or something like that.

That program makes marmalade out of the vectors. Don't use copy and paste out of thoose programs either. I think they convert them to wmf or something, that is a very bad file format.

Comment: Wmf is not inherently a bad format it just has some fairly interesting notions of precision. Thus if you do not anticipate and model according to how it works you get nasty surprises on conversion

Comment: Hi Rafael, i'm using illustrator and converted the text on curves before.